# Changing the author field in SP Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, metadata

We have a document Library wherein we display the Author(Meta Data) of the document. This is the name of the user who created and uploaded the document. We have a scenario where another user modifies the same document and uploads it by overriding the existing one. However we still see the first user under Author. Why is it so? What should we do to get the latest (modifier's) name.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add a field to the view "Modified By"; Author field refers to the first entity that created the document. Modified By shows latest entity that modified the item.

If you would like to change the author you need to do it via PowerShell or create Event Receiver to overwrite the value of the field.

Answer (score 1):

The latest modifiers' name is in the field "Modified By". Author always shows the person who uploaded the first version of the document.

To have the latest modifier in the Author-Field you would need to delete the file and then upload it again .